# remap port 80 to 22

Tags: ssh, iptables, port

I would like to remap incoming requests on port 80 to port 22 and tried the following: `sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 22` but still, `ssh -i key user@host -p 80` would not let me connect, why not I'm wondering?

**EDIT1**

```
$ sudo iptables-save -c
sudo: unable to resolve host DevRon
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Sep  3 00:23:20 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [21:1260]
:INPUT ACCEPT [21:1260]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [254:15716]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [254:15716]
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 22
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 22
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep  3 00:23:20 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Sep  3 00:23:20 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [41307:2896000]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [41123:2886089]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep  3 00:23:20 2018
```

Comment: are you doing this from remote or from host itself?

Comment: @A.B from remote, I don't have "physical" access to this machine

Comment: The whole `iptables-save -c` output would help best

Comment: @A.B please see **EDIT1** above, the `8080` rule is just a remnant from testing i've done - that's also the reason why to `80`-rule shows up twice....

Comment: There's no hit on those rules, even if they (well the 1st) should be working. Are you able to see such traffic with tcpdump  -n -i *interface* tcp port 80 (tcpdump captures before nat, so you should see something there)

Comment: @A.B I don't see anything but I try to login using `$ ssh -i aws-cloudparc.pem ubuntu@host -p 80` but when i remove `-p 80` it works just fine....

Comment: That means port 80 is filtered before, outside of this system

Comment: @A.B I don't know, this is a Amazon AWS machine and I thought that should work fine.... hmm...  I'll install Apache to see what I get on port 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on: https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/change-ssh-to-listen-on-two-ports.47365/

> SSH can listen on multiple ports. Just add additional ports in sshd_config like > this:
>
> Port 22
>   Port 8888

Comment: out of curiosity: did it work for port 80 ?

Comment: @A.B yes, i didn't actually try 80 but I'd expect it to work just fine!

Comment: considering the discussion before (where even tcpdump couldn't detect traffic on port 80), i'd have wanted to know in the end if it would really work specifically on port 80

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is for SSH to listen on Port 80, you can add a second port option in /etc/ssh/sshd_config like:

```
Port 22
Port 80
```

Comment: its lots easier than network port mapping :-)

Comment: but it looks like it doesn't let me config two ports on that line, upon restart of ssh I get an error: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 5: Badly formatted`

Comment: appolgies - updated.